# What is convex combination of two points?

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I am studying algorithms and i saw a definition like the following:

Given $3$ points $p_1 = (x_1, y_1)$, $p_2 = (x_2, y_2)$ and
$p_3 = (x_3, y_3)$, $p_3$ is a convex combination of $p_1$ and $p_2$ iff
$\exists 0 \le a \le 1$ such that:

(i) $x_3 = x_1 + (1 −a )x_2$
(ii) $y_3 = y_1 + (1 − a)y_2$

If $p_3$ is a convex combination of $p_1$ and $p_2$, we also write
$p_3 = p_1 + (1 −a )p_2$

My question is, i did not understand what this definition means, and what does convex combination means intuitively? I appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: You mean $p_3 = ap_1 + (1-a)p_2$. And this means geometrically that $p_3$ is on the line between $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The point $ap_1+(1-a)p_2$ can also be written as $p_2+a(p_1-p_2)$. Perhaps you recognize this as a parametric representation of a line through $p_2$ with direction vector $p_1-p_2$ (with $a$ as the parameter).

When $a=0$, $ap_1+(1-a)p_2=p_2$. And when $a=1$, $ap_1+(1-a)p_2=p_1$. So the points $ap_1+(1-a)p_2$ with $0\le a\le1$ make up the line segment between the two given points.

Answer (score 4):

It just means that you can get the point $p_3$ by simply adding the other points ($p_1$, $p_2$). But you don't want to just add them instead you'd like to give some sort of "weight" to each point.

Simply put, convex combination means `weighted sum` with the condition that the weights have to sum to 1.

In general, for a vector ($x_1, x_2, ...., x_n$), the convex combination is:

$\alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2 + \alpha_3 x_3+ ... \alpha_n x_n \hspace{2em}$

where $\hspace{0.5em} \alpha_i \ge 0 \hspace{0.5em} $ **and** $\hspace{0.5em} \alpha_1+ \alpha_2+ \alpha_3+ ... +\alpha_n = 1$

Answer (score 1):

A less abstract and more meaningful example of convex combination can be got from the real world, for example from the production of two types of goods by means of a single machine. The machine has to work two lots **sharing the same productive period of time** $T$ [$T$ is measured in working days]. Let be $t_1$ the time spent by machine for working the first item and  $t_2$  the time spent by machine for working the second item:

$ T = t_1 + t_2 $

Two vectors $p_1$ and $p_2$ express the productivity of the machine as $p_i$ units of output of the i-th kind of product during one working day, while at the end of period T the total amount $q$ of the two items worked by the machine is:

$ q = t_1p_1 + t_2p_2$ where $t_1+t_2=T$

If we designate by ai the fraction of time period $T$ for which the machine is occupied with the i-th kind of output, we can define the **intensity** (*level of activity*) of the machine as $a_1 = t_1/T$ and $a_2=t_2/T$, so that $a_1 + a_2=1$.

As a result

$p = a_1p_1 + a_2p_2$ where $a_1 + a_2=1$

So, the convex combination $p$ designates the productivity of the machine as units of output worked during one period of time $T$ being $p=q/T$.

Now, we can image a vector space of n dimensions where every dimension stands for a different machine. In this way, a vector designates the n output performed by every single machine and m vectors represent m different kind of output performed by n machines. Again, the n machines *share the same time of production* and the total production is a **convex combination**.